# Запрос с одинаковыми параметрами, но разными результатами | RTK Query | Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux

Я недавно изучил redux-toolkit и мне понравилась идея rtk, но у меня сразу возник вопрос: а что мне вернется, если данные, отправленные в запрос одинаковы, но вот результаты разные?

Как пример: есть запрос api.getMessage({subject_id}). При его вызове я запрашиваю последние сообщения по указанному чату, но результаты могут сильно отличаться. Возникает вопрос, если я использую такое в RTK, что он мне вернет? Уже кешированные данные или же новые?

И есть ли возможно записывать ответ в нужном формате в определенные slice, а не в отдельный? Т.е. есть ли возможность конфигурации модели ответа?

Может, вопрос для вас очевидный, но я действительно не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если данные изменяются в другой части приложения post/put запросом, то чтобы при следующем get запросе данные были актуальными, надо в конфиг апишки добавить поле tagTypes и в апишке запросов указать с каким тэгом ведётся работа: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#tags.
Если же данные могут быть изменены вне приложения, то надо настроить время хранения кэша (по умолчанию = 60сек)
А конфигурацию ответа можно задать в специальном поле transformResponse (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-query-responses-with-transformresponse), предназначенном для этого
либо в кастомном хуке:

```js
// rtk query
const tasksApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "tasksApi",
  baseQuery: ...,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTasks: ...,
  }),
});
const { useGetTasksQuery } = tasksApi;

// кастомный хук
export function useGetTasks() {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetTasksQuery();

  // конфигурация респонса
  const model = data && { id: data.id, task: data.task, ...data }

  return {
    tasks: model,
    isLoading,
    error,
  };
}
```